# Python multiple inheritance questions

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Sorry if this question has been asked before, I could not find the answer while searching other questions.

I'm new to Python and I'm having issues with multiple inheritance. Suppose I have 2 classes, B and C, which inherit from the same class A, which are defined as follows:

```
class B(A):
    def foo():
        ...
        return

    def bar():
        ...
        return


class C(A):
    def foo():
        ...
        return

    def bar():
        ...
        return
```

I now want to define another class D, which inherits from both B and C. D should inherit B's implementation of foo, but C's implementation of bar. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: this is known as the diamond problem - http://mypythonnotes.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/python-multiple-inheritance-and-the-diamond-problem/

Comment: it is better to explicitly say what do you want, in `D.__init__` you can `self.bar = C.bar`

Comment: `super().foo()` in class D will call `B.foo()` once `B` is before `C` in the mro

Comment: @m.wasowski I think it would be better to do this directly in the class definition than to do it on an instance-by-instance basis at `__init__` time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resisting the temptation to say "avoid this situation in the first place", one (not necessarily elegant) solution could be to wrap the methods explicitly:

```
class A: pass

class B( A ):
    def foo( self ): print( 'B.foo')
    def bar( self ): print( 'B.bar')

class C( A ):
    def foo( self ): print( 'C.foo')
    def bar( self ): print( 'C.bar')

class D( B, C ):
    def foo( self ): return B.foo( self )
    def bar( self ): return C.bar( self )
```

Alternatively you can make the method definitions explicit, without wrapping:

```
class D( B, C ):
    foo = B.foo
    bar = C.bar
```